# can't activate anaconda venv that do exist

Tags: anaconda

I'm building a website with Django. I built a Django virtual environment with anaconda. A few days ago I have updated the anaconda and after that, I have a problem with activating a virtual environment

When I trying to activate a virtual environment with `source activate django`, the terminal responds with this message:

```
Could not find conda environment: django
You can list all discoverable environments with `conda info --envs`.
```

where apparently there is a virtual environment name 'django'.

When I try `conda info --envs` on a terminal, it shows:

```
WARNING: The conda.compat module is deprecated and will be removed in a future release.
# conda environments:
#
                         /Users/myname/anaconda3/envs/django
base                     /anaconda
```

I can't see the first one's name but only directory. However, if I open anaconda navigator and see the list of virtual environments, I can see the environment name 'django', and can activate it with a play button. Also, I can see one more environment name 'anaconda3' which is not even displayed on a terminal by command `conda info --envs`.

Is there any possible reason for this?